# Descargar archivo de aplicación Android con Ionic + InAppBrowser

Tags: nodejs, ionic, cordova

Estoy intentando adaptar un servicio que ya se encuentra desplegado en la nube a una aplicación para Android con **IONIC V7.1.1** + **InAppBrowser**. He realizado diversas pruebas en mi smartphone y todo funciona de maravilla excepto que al momento de descargar una imagen no sucede nada. El código que genera la dicha, es mediante canvas y luego se muestra un botón para poder realizar la correspondiente descarga. En el navegador siempre ha funcionado bien, pero en la App intenté con el siguiente código y no he tenido éxito.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser/ngx';
import { App } from '@capacitor/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit{

  constructor(private browser: InAppBrowser) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const browserInstance = this.browser.create(
      "https://miservicio.com/", 
      "_self", 
      "location=no,hidenavigationbuttons=true,hideurlbar=true,zoom=no"
      );
    browserInstance.on("exit").subscribe((evt) => {
      App.exitApp();
    });
    browserInstance.on('loadstart').subscribe(
      (data) => {
       console.log("URL IS",data.url);
       this.downloadfile(data.url)
    });
  }
}
```

El error que sale es el siguiente: **La propiedad 'downloadfile' no existe en el tipo 'HomePage'**